# Unregister user account from devices in a Windows Domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10, microsoft-365

In a Windows Domain with Microsoft 365 when a user has used more than 20 devices they get an error they have have to unregister in order to sign into a new Windows 10 workstation. Does anyone know of a way to unregister devices that are found on the page https://myaccount.microsoft.com/device-list from powershell for users?

Here is the help guide for the page so you can see the page I am talking about:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/manage-your-work-or-school-account-connected-devices-from-the-devices-page-6b5a735d-0a7f-4e94-8cfd-f5da6bc13d4e

Comment: If you have an OnPrem (local) Active Directory that is synchronized with MS365, you should be able to do it OnPrem. Can you try this: **Open MMC** 'Active Directory Users and Computers', **Menu -> View -> Check** *Users, Contacts, Groups, and Computers as Containers*. Then, when you double-click on a User account, you should see all devices associated with the account and be able to delete the ones you want...

Comment: I don't see a place that lists the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a user from a device using the Azure User Details Devices Page or using the command line tool Remove-AzureADDeviceRegisteredUser.

Additional information:
https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UserDetailsMenuBlade/Devices/userId/(User GUID)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureaddeviceregistereduser?view=azureadps-2.0